# Padding of Title is outside of the div

Tags: css

i created a jsfiddle where you can see the problem. The padding of the title is outside the div:

http://jsfiddle.net/h8Guf/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div>
    <h2><a href="#">This is a test text</a></h2>
</div>

/* CSS */
div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}

div h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;   
}

div h2 a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block`, Try following

```
div h2 a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: green;
  display: block; /* Added Rule */
}
```

[<kbd>**Demo Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/h8Guf/1/)

Answer (score 2):

because your `<h2>` is positioned absolutely, the padding overruns the containing `<div>` there are a few ways to fix this.  one would be to change the `bottom` value like so

```
div h2 {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;   
}
```

this will compensate for your padding

Comment: Thank you too. Now i have 2 different ways. Which one is better?

Comment: it pretty much just comes down to ease of code maintainability, but i would say that the other answer, using `display: block;` is better.  With that method if you wanted to change the padding there would be no issue.  with my solution, if you change the padding you will also have to change the `bottom` value to go along with it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you celeriko for your help.